# Minimum Supporting Android and iOS version for tensorflowlite

Tags: android, ios, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite, yolo

I searched on https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide and some other forums but I could not get a definitive answer for what are the minimum supporting OS versions for tensorflowlite. My requirement is to support custom keras and YOLO models from Android 5.0 and iOS 6.0.

Answer (score 2):

TensorFlowLite for iOS [requires at least iOS 11](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/swift/TensorFlowLiteSwift.podspec#L17).

TensorFlowLite for Android [requires at least SDK 19 (KitKat)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.13.0/tensorflow/lite/java/AndroidManifest.xml#L7).

Comment: Good info, but both links no longer work.

Comment: I've update the links to the current files in the repo and updated the information about which iOS version is now supported.